# Access Token from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, access-token, sharepoint-online

I'm having trouble getting an access token for my third party application that will do CRUD operations to my SharePoint site due to this Access Token not being provided.

this is the error

```
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'
```

I've tried sending both raw JSON and Form-data as a body with 'grant_type' key but that same error is returned.

post URL:

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<tenant ID>/tokens/OAuth/2
```

body:

```
{
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "resource":<resource>,
    "client_id":<client_id>,
    "client_secret":<client_secret>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open postman and create a POST request with below details :

**URL** : [https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenantid}/tokens/OAuth/2](https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/%7Btenantid%7D/tokens/OAuth/2)

**Headers** :

Content-Type       : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Body** :

```json
grant_type: client_credentials  
client_id: {clientid}@{tenantid}  
client_secret: {clientsecretvalue}  
resource: 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{tenant}.sharepoint.com@{tenantid}
```

2. Click Send button and you can get access_token on response's Body tab.
3. Open a new tab and create GET request as below :

**URL** : https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{name}/_api/web/lists/

**Headers** :

```
Authorization: Bearer {accesstoken}  
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
```

4. Click send button to view the list of SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the body content in headers? I think there might be some parameters format is incorrect. Here are some tutorials that help to get started with token request:

- https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/
- https://anexinet.com/blog/getting-an-access-token-for-sharepoint-online/

Here is a test:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't your URL point to a specific tenant? should I remove the Tenant ID from the URL?